# Cancellation support for TcpClient.ConnectAsync method

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, tcpclient, cancellation-token

I am hoping to get some opinions on adding resilience to a piece that I am working on that involves creating multiple `TcpClient` connections asynchronously to various servers and once the TCP connections are successfully established, then storing the `TcpClient` in sort of a collection (Just an excerpt from the requirement)

This is what I have so far:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly TcpClient _client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    private static SslStream _stream;

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5000);
        var connectTask = _client.ConnectAsync("10.14.16.24", 56564);

        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, connectTask);
        if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
            _client.Dispose();

        try
        {
            await connectTask;
            _stream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), false);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**:
In case a timeout happens, the `connectTask` status is still "`WaitingForActivation`" until the `ConnectAsync` method returns either `Faulted` or `RanToCompletion`. How to cancel this task, knowing that `ConnectAsync` doesn't support `CancellationToken`

Any suggestions, or improvements are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As an extension for @Kelly Elton's answer, it seems that you should catch

- in .NET Framework 4.x `NullReferenceException`
- in .NET Core 2.x and 3.x `ObjectDisposedException`
- in .NET 5 `SocketException`

So perhaps the correct catch statement would be

```cs
#if NET5_0 //_OR_GREATER?
catch (SocketException ex) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
#elif NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
#elif NETFRAMEWORK && NET40_OR_GREATER
catch (NullReferenceException ex) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
#else
#error Untested target framework, use with care!
catch (???) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
#endif
```

Comment: There is now a cancelable variant in .NET 5.0, hooray!

Answer (score 3):

Your mileage may vary based on which `.net` you're using

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpClientCancellation
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static async Task ConnectAsync(this TcpClient tcpClient, string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
            if (tcpClient == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tcpClient));
            }

            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            using (cancellationToken.Register(() => tcpClient.Close())) {
                try {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port).ConfigureAwait(false);
                } catch (NullReferenceException) when (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's up with `NullReferenceException` catch?

Comment: It's the exception that's thrown from within `ConnectAsync` in my experience when you call `Close()`.

Comment: In .NET 5, you should catch `SocketException`

Answer (score 1):

I am using these generic methods; they can add timeout and cancellation tokens for any async task. You need to use **using var tcpClient** to make sure the client be disposed after the cancellation exception raise or actively dispose your client

Let me know if you see any problem so I can fix it accordingly.

```
public static async Task<T> RunTask<T>(Task<T> task, int timeout = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await RunTask((Task)task, timeout, cancellationToken);
    return await task;
}

public static async Task RunTask(Task task, int timeout = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (timeout == 0) timeout = -1;

    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);
    await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompleted)
        throw new TimeoutException();

    await task;
}
```

**Usage**

```
using var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
await RunTask(tcpClient.ConnectAsync("yourhost.com", 443), cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: Just a minor nitpick but if both tasks complete at the same time you treat it as a timeout anyway.

Comment: @Ramon Good point, we can check the completion of the main task before timeout but in most cases, it doesn't matter due to the nature of timeout business, even if it really happens.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but in my opinion you don't really cancel the task, you just abandon it and let it run in the background until it completes by itself. In many cases this will work, but this is not an universal solution. (a) If the Task returns an unmanaged resource, it will leak away, and (b) if that Task has heavy CPU usage, it will do this until its completion.

Comment: @Rolf You are right, But there is no way to cancel a task without its CancellationTokenSource. The caller need to manage the original Task disposal in TimeoutException such as TcpClient.Dispose. We can also pass CancellationTokenSource, but it may not be available. By the way, I prefer this one

Comment: Yes, that was my problem too - TcpClient.ConnectAsync. But yesterday I learned: instead of awaiting that Task, you can call Wait() on it. And Wait can take a CancellationToken, this works!

Comment: @Rolf it does really work, but is not Async anymore ... it should be packed in a task and than it would be also an acceptable solution!

Comment: In net8 there is also: WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) which avoids the need to wrap Wait in a Task

Answer (score 0):

@Rolf: So true! After tearing my hair out for hours trying to make a TcpClient have a user-definable connection timeout, I stumbled upon this thread and using the .Wait() on the ConnectAsync method makes it as simple as this:

```
  Dim cli As New TcpClient()
  If cli.ConnectAsync(TargetEndpoint.Address, TargetEndpoint.Port).Wait(1000) Then
     ' Do your work with the TcpClient
  Else
     Throw New TimeoutException("Failed to connect to the endpoint within the timeout")
  End If
```

No need for any messing around with cancellation tokens or overseeing Async methods.

Comment: I did this, but actually got unobserved exceptions by the underlying task which was spawned when calling ConnectAsync. Since this task will eventually throw an exception when you Dispose or close the TcpClient.